# Fetch restful api

Tags: node.js, express, pug

What is the syntax to fetch API with Nodejs im trying fetch but it says fetch is not defined[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jHbU.png)

Comment: Node doesn't have fetch, you have to use a polyfill like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

Comment: thanks man i really appriciate this

Answer (score 0):

Fetch does not exist in nodejs. For that you have to make use of some module to make fetch requests.

An example is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

npm install node-fetch

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {method: 'POST', body: 'a=1'});
const data = await response.json();
```